# I'm trying to run gedit in cygwin, but receiving error

Tags: cygwin, gedit

I'm trying to run some normal text editor in cygwin (version 2.4.1(0.293/5/3)).
I've really disappointed and frustrated with emacs :( So I downloaded and installed gedit as a part of cygwin package, but when I'm trying to run it, I receive:

```
$ gedit

Unable to init server: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

(gedit:8196): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I understand that it can be somehow connected with security issues (it runs on multiuser win10 PC), but I cannot find out how to solve it....

Please help!

Comment: That's karma punishing you for giving up on Emacs.

Comment: That's karma pushing me to install ubuntu :)

Comment: Are you ssh'd into this server? If so you need to enable "X forwarding" in your ssh client. But if you're looking for a no-nonsense editor that will actually work, use `nano`.

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem and was able to solve. Your case may be the same

1. [install Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html#setup-cygwin-x-installing)
2. open cygwin and start x11 server by  typing

   startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &
3. set DISPLAY environment variable as explained [here](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-local-apps.html) by typing

   export DISPLAY=:0.0
4. Start gedit normally

Comment: Still getting this error : 
Unable to init server: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

(gedit:8108): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0

Comment: Do you have the package xinit installed? Try to start startxwin   without redirecting anything (without the >/dev/null 2>&1 &) parts and see if it works. If it does not, check if xinit  is installed and install it if it is not.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution **works** if you follow the instruction and install/configure the required packages.

Comment: Thanks I just needed to run `startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0):

This (startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &   export DISPLAY=:0.0)   work for temporary, not permanent. It is needed to type each time I close terminal.

Comment: You have to add it to ~/.bashrc